# C# login examples

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having trouble hiding my main form for a login form. Once user has logged in to close login form and show main form.

I have been confusing myself that much I have deleted all code and started fresh. I can hide the login form fine.

I was unable to hide the main form called with

```
Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

Login form looks like this:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class LoginForm : Form
    {
        public LoginForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username;
            string password;

            username = TB_username.Text;
            password = TB_password.Text;

            if (User.Login(username, password))
            {
                Globals._Login = true;

                // Close login form
                this.Dispose(false);

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I cant figure out how to hide then show the main form once login has passed.

Thanks any examples would be great

Comment: What happens when you call "Hide()" in the MainForm?

Comment: Unrelated but consider using `SecureString` instead of `String` for the password portion of the login.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. Use `ShowDialog()` to open the login form. Then you don’t need to hide or disable the Mainform yourself. In fact, if you want the login form to appear at the beginning of the application, consider showing it before even loading the Mainform:

   ```
   static void Main()
   {
       Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
       Application.EnableVisualStyles();
       DialogResult result;
       using (var loginForm = new LoginForm())
           result = loginForm.ShowDialog();
       if (result == DialogResult.OK)
       {
           // login was successful
           Application.Run(new Mainform());
       }
   }
   ```
2. Inside your login form, in `button1_Click`, use

   ```
   DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
   ```

   to close the login form and pass the `OK` result to the Mainform.
   There is no need for `Dispose()`.

Comment: Can any one please  explain how I will get the user details  to the Mainform.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ShowDialog() function on the login form to load the login form from within the main form of the application. This will prevent the MainForm being displayed until after the LoginForm has finished.

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var loginForm = new LoginForm();
    loginForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So ... Here is my login :) You can like it or don't like, but so ... This is my solution.

```
    private void FRIIB_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            QueryBuilder.insql = Crypto.DecryptStringAES(Model.DecryptRegisteryValue("inSQL"), "inSQL");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        } // getting connection string
        if (!(new Func<bool>(() =>
                {
                    Func<bool> l = null; l = () =>
                    {
                        using (LoginForm loginDialog = new LoginForm())
                        {
                            loginDialog.ShowDialog();
                            loginDialog.Focus();
                            if (loginDialog.IsExit) return false;
                            else
                                if (loginDialog.IsAuthorized) return true;
                                else return l();
                        }
                    }; return l();
                }
              )()
            )) Close(); 
        else w8( () => LoadData() );
    }
```

and here is some description for code :

```
    private void w8(Action action)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        Application.DoEvents();
        action();
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }

Public Class DamnLogin
    Private db As FRIIB

    Public Sub New(ByVal connection As String)
        db = New FRIIB(connection)
    End Sub

    Public Function Login(ByVal name As String, ByVal password As String) As Boolean
        Dim GetUser = _
           From u In db.GetTable(Of [User])() _
           Where u.Name = name _
           And u.Password = password _
           Select u
        Return GetUser.Count = 0
    End Function
End Class

let Login usename password = 
    new LinqBase.DamnLogin(insql) |> fun damn ->
        not <| damn.Login(usename,password)
```

and login form

```
public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
    bool isAuthorized;
    bool exit;

    public bool IsAuthorized    { get { return this.isAuthorized;   } }
    public bool IsExit          { get { return this.exit;           } }

    public LoginForm()
    {
        isAuthorized    = false;
        exit            = false;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        exit = true; 
        this.Close();
    }

    private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Login.Text != "")
        {
            if (Login.Text.ToUpper() == "ADMIN")
            {
                if (Password.Text == Crypto.DecryptStringAES(Model.DecryptRegisteryValue("Password"), "Password"))
                    isAuthorized = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (QueryBuilder.Login(Login.Text, Password.Text))
                    isAuthorized = true;
            }
        }

        this.Close();
    }
}
```