# Open another Form from Main Form and then close the Main Form on C# Project

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I working on a C# Windows Form Project where the main form is a Login Form that I will call another Form when the Login is successfully done, but my question is, how can I set the called form as the main and then close the one created initially?

Comment: Have you tried looking for the answer yourself? You can easily find this out.

Comment: Use the [.Show()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [.Hide()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.hide%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods built into `.NET`.

Comment: @Brian this is a winforms question, not WPF

Comment: @stuartd - Winforms has those methods too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create winform login dialog and keep looping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140852/how-to-create-winform-login-dialog-and-keep-looping) or [C# login examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507855/c-sharp-login-examples) or [How to Implement login form and main form without more instances in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375892/how-to-implement-login-form-and-main-form-without-more-instances-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Please see my this answer that might be useful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59891244/4190858

Comment: Please see my this answer that might be useful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59891244/4190858

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will likely want to simply `Show()` the new form, and `Hide()` the login form.

```
var secondForm = new MyForm(); // or whatever the name of your form is
secondForm.Show();
this.Hide();
```

You could call `Close()` instead of `Hide()` on the login form, but that would end the application. You can see this in the `Main` method in `Program.cs`, which probably looks like:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new LoginForm());
    }
```

Once that initial `LoginForm` from `Application.Run` closes, the program ends. You can change this by changing what `Main()` does (i.e. which form it opens as the initial form). For example, you could set the second form as your main form, then if the user isn't logged in, hide itself in the `Form_Load` event.

So depending on your workflow, it's helpful to think of these forms in terms of `Show()`, `Hide()`, and `Close()`. Any number of forms could exist at any time, and you simply control which ones are shown to the user depending on your workflow.

If you want to explicitly exit your application, but the initial form is hidden, you can call `Application.Exit()` from someplace else.